# Can we set foreign key on a unique column that contains null?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, foreign-keys

What I learned was we can set a foreign key on a unique constrained column, and unique constraint will allow one null (correct me if I am wrong).

My question is that in oracle can we create a foreign key  on a column referred on unique constraint column which is in another table and has null?

If yes, how is that possible?

Comment: The values in the column don't affect whether or not you can declare a foreign key, so the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: I see you posted many questions, but never accepted an answer, even when it seems that you've got good ones. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find something more on what to do when someone answers you.

Comment: "set a foreign key on" & "based on" are not clear. Please use standard terms. We declare a FK in a table & it references a list of columns in another table. Also "unique constraint will allow one null" is unclear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please tell us why can't you find yes-or-no in the manual or any FK documentation. Please give example data & DDL and say where you think there is problem. [ask]

Comment: Standard SQL allows any number of NULLs in a UNIQUE column that allows NULLs. SQL Server only allows one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we create a foreign key based on unique constraint which has null ?

The syntax allows us to create a foreign key which references a unique key. However, I think it would be if not exactly bad practice then at least peculiar practice to do so. Primary keys are the norm.

> If yes, how is that possible?

It's possible because a foreign key column can itself be optional. A foreign key constrains us to entering a value in the child column which is present in the referenced primary key column. However, if we put a null in the child column then the foreign key is not enforced. This is true whether the foreign key references a primary key or a unique key.

Obviously, if the child column is mandatory (defined as NOT NULL) then we cannot put a null in it, and it really doesn't matter whether the referenced column is a unique key or a primary key.

Comment: The question isn't clear but they seem to mean, as you say, why can we declare a FK referencing a UNIQUE that is not NOT NULL. The answer is that when not NULL the referencing table FK value has to appear in the referenced table, and there being nulls there too doesn't stop us from enforcing the constraint. But you don't address that; you switch to addressing nulls in the referencing table when the issue is the referenced table. The "because" in your "It's possible because" is not sound. The fact that a referencing FK could be null has no bearing on whether the referenced UNIQUE could be null.